# How to enable the browser context menu in dojox.grid.DataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, dojo, contextmenu, right-click

I'm trying to get the browser context menu to work inside a dojox.grid.DataGrid. When I right-click on the grid now, nothing happens. I tried overriding onCellContextMenu, onRowContextMenu, doContextMenu, and oncontextmenu with empty functions on the grid instance, but that didn't work. The method onCellContextMenu is called on a right-click, but it still doesn't show a context menu. I think the event is being stopped at another level, but I'm not sure where to look.

The grid has a list of links, and I want users to be able to right click on links so they can open them in a new tab. I know that I can make a custom context menu to provide that functionality, but I'd like to know how to disable this behavior in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that this may be a bit late, but I ran into the same exact problem and found a resolution by studying the source code and asking around the dojo community chat. The solution involves creating a custom Grid widget that has the following modifications:

1. Create a custom _FocusManager that your custom grid will use, where the only update is removing the functionality of the doContextMenu method which executes a dojo.stopEvent by default -
   `//extension to remove contextmenu dojo.stopEvent
   dojo.declare('myGrid.dojox.grid._FocusManager', dojox.grid._FocusManager, {
       doContextMenu: function() {}
   });`
2. Remove the original callbacks in the grid that execute dojo.stopEvent by default:

   //remove original callbacks that call stopEvent

   ```
   onRowContextMenu: function(e) {},
   onHeaderContextMenu: function(e) {}
   ```

Here is a working example that I was given at the community chat: http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/SqYXd/

Comment: Regarding that solution: "Here is a working example that I was given at the community chat: http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/SqYXd/": it works great with Dojo Datagrids indeed. Unfortunately it does NOT for EnhancedGrids (the binding is kept on the grid, so even if you do not bind any Dijit menus on the grid, the browser menu still will not appear). Any "enhanced" solution for that?... A.R.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly the solution you want for displaying the context menu, but have you tried telling your users to Ctrl-leftClick on those links rather right-click to display the context menu ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dijit.menu in a div and set its display to none.  Here's an example where the context menu and grid are contained in a dijit ContentPane:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="MyGrid">
    <div id="myGridContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
    <div id="myGridContextMenu" dojoType="dijit.Menu" style="display: none;">
        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" id="myGridContextMenu.delete" onClick="deleteItem">Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will also need to connect the menu to your grid when you create it:

```
var myGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({ ..., onRowContextMenu: myGridcontextMenu },...);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, it still doesn't show a context menu.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question. You want the Firefox/chrome/IE menu to show up with context, as it would on an image for example? Rather than one you hook in. So treat it just like another link on the page?